# PHP - SQLite unexpected return array results

Tags: php, sqlite

First time playing with SQLite, I've created a database and table and set the column `id` as the `primary key unique`.

I've inserted some data into the table and can see the data when I do :

`SELECT * FROM members;`

However when I run the following query I'm not getting the results I expected.

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE plan = 'User' AND id = '$users_id'");
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result->fetchArray());
    echo "</pre>";
```

I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 124578986532-784512986452
    [id] => 124578986532-784512986452
    [1] => User
    [plan] => User
    [2] => 54890
    [phone] => 54890
    [3] => 698-78450
    [staffID] => 698-78450
    [4] => WestWing
    [location] => WestWing
    [5] => 1
    [active] => 1
)
```

Which is the correct result, but why do I get duplicates for each returned entry ?

ie: Why `[0] & [id]`, `[1] & [plan]` ??

As each users ID is unique searching for it will only ever return one result set, how do I use the results as variables I can use elsewhere within the page ?

eg: `$id = $result['id']` ?

Thanks

Comment: `fetchArray` Returns a result row as an associatively or numerically indexed array or both.

Comment: Read a manual, __please__

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3result.fetcharray.php :) specially `Parameters` section

Comment: `fetchArray(1)` seems to have sorted the duplication. How do I use the returned results as variables ?

Answer (score 0):

`fetcharray` contains `numerical array` and `associative array`, so your result should be

**For Named index array**

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE plan = 'User' AND id = '$users_id'");
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result->fetchArray(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
echo "</pre>";
```

**Here the Crossponding Data**

`$result->fetchArray(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)` -The rows are arrays with both numeric and named indexes

`$result->fetchArray(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` -The rows are arrays with named indexes.

`$result->fetchArray(PDO::FETCH_NUM)` - The rows are arrays with numeric indexes.